# Problema Con un if en java

Tags: java

Estaba intentando hacer que si eres mayor de 18 pues que te salga un mensaje si no eres mayor que te salga otro mensaje y hice el código(Creo que esta bien)

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner myObj  = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduce Tu Edad");

        String Edad = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Tu Edad es: " + Edad);
        if (Edad < 18){
            System.out.println("Eres Menor De Edad");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Eres Mayor De Edad");
        }
        }
}
```

pero me sale un error en el if donde esta la edad me pone un fallo y que yo sepa esta bien

Comment: Declarando la edad como entero desde un principio te permite simplificar también para la impresión usando un [operador ternario](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator): `System.out.println(Edad < 18 ? "Eres Menor De Edad": "Eres Mayor De Edad");` Con eso no necesitas el `if`.

Answer (score 3):

Estás declarando la variable `edad` como una cadena de texto (`String`). Tienes que declararlo como un entero (`int`) para poder compararlo.

Esto no podrás hacerlo ya que estás recogiendo la edad por consola y al recoger un valor por consola lo que hace es recogerlo como cadena de texto. Por tanto, deberás hacer un *casting* para convertirlo a entero. Para ello deberás utilizar `Integer.parseInt(edad)`

Código funcional:

```java
class Main{
    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner myObj  = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduce Tu Edad");

        String Edad = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Tu Edad es: " + Edad);
        if (Integer.parseInt(Edad) < 18){
            System.out.println("Eres Menor De Edad");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Eres Mayor De Edad");
        }
        }
}
```

O, si te parece más comprensible:

```java
class Main{
    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner myObj  = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduce Tu Edad");

        String Edad = myObj.nextLine();
        int edadEntero = Integer.parseInt(Edad)
        System.out.print("Tu Edad es: " + Edad);
        if (edadEntero < 18){
            System.out.println("Eres Menor De Edad");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Eres Mayor De Edad");
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Comment: @m4rkus para eso estamos!

Answer (score 2):

También puedes declarar la variable **Edad** como **int** desde el principio

```
int Edad = myObj.nextInt();
```

Comment: Esta es incluso mejor solución que la que he dado yo arriba

Answer (score 1):

Ya que tienes el modelo if-else puedes usar el [operador ternario](https://decodigo.com/java-operador-ternario) que hace que el código sea más compacto.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myObj  = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduce Tu Edad: ");
        int edad = myObj.nextInt();
        System.out.println(edad < 18 ? "Eres Menor De Edad": "Eres Mayor De Edad");
}
```

**Observación**
Las variables en java se declaran en **minúscula** y si es una palabra compuesta se usa la **notación Camel Case**